# Just noticed this Bell-Shaped Icon In The Taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, taskbar, notification-area

[image]

Located first on the left. If I hover my mouse over it, it says "Chrome - Notifications". I have never noticed this before:

Is it new ?

What is its function & is it related to running the Chrome Web Browser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Some websites, apps and extensions, such as Google Calendar, can show
>   notifications on your computer desktop. Google Chrome alerts you by
>   default whenever a site wants permission to automatically show
>   notifications.
>
> When you receive a notification, you’ll see a message appear in the
>   lower right corner of your computer screen and an icon  appear in the
>   notification area (also called the system tray) on Windows and the
>   menu bar on Mac. Click on the icon to open the Chrome Notification
>   Centre to see older notifications that you have not dismissed.
>
> Windows only: The notification area is a temporary source for notifications,
>   so the Chrome Notification Centre may be hidden. If you don’t see your
>   Chrome notifications expand the notification area to see hidden
>   notifications.

[Source](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?hl=en-GB)

Comment: Thanks for that. Has that been around for quite a while ?

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't know - I can't find any thing official